# Restrict select2 to a max of 6 choices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an non-multiple dropdown select2 with Ajax. I need to limit the selected choices to 6.

I tried using `maximumSelectionSize` but this only works on a multiple.

I then looked at:

```js
.on('select2-selecting', function(e){

// counting the ids but this did not work
      var hasId = ($('[id^=select2-chosen-]').length);

});
```

I'm really struggling on this, so any help is most appreciated.

Comment: i'm sorry, i did not get what you meant by non-multiple and at the same time 6 selected choices ?

Comment: As per the documentation on their [example page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) "Select2 also supports multi-value select boxes. The select below is declared with the multiple attribute"

Answer (score 0):

On select you can return the options value and limit it to 6 characters long.

```
.on('select2-selecting', function(e){
     var returnValue = $(this).val().substr(0,6); //remove anything after 6 charaters.
    console.info(returnValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jamie, and the others.
`var returnValue = $(this).val().substr(0,6);`
with return  `[objec`  (the word object minus characters)  what i really need is to limit the total number of selected values to 6.  What i think I need to do, but cannot get it working is:
1) Push the object to an array as [0]
2) Push any further selected items to the same array.
3) When the array reaches [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] it will add `disabled` on the input. 

Things to remember, I use select2, this needs to happen on.change, the val() is [object, object]  so maybe not using val() is better.

Comment: Please add the full HTML and JS... Then I'll be able to help you. x

Comment: Also could you paste the contents of the console in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Jamie. 
The HTML is as follows:
`<input class="select2" type='hidden' />`
The JS is rather long, its very similar to the demo https://select2.github.io/examples.html and there is no problem with this. However its not a multiple search, so we cannot use `maximumSelectionLength` but .on('sect2-selecting` or something similar to count until 6 entires then add disabled to the input. I have appended the selected entries to a `<li></li>` in another div. I can post more info, if required on JSFiddle, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: I have put the code in a JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/tellmehow/5tv1uxqr/
It will not work given the environment of JSFiddle, but you should get an understanding of what I'm trying to do. Limit selected options to 6. Thanks.

Comment: So you want there to only be 6 different options inside the actualy dropdown. So 6 `<option>`'s?

Comment: there will be more than six options, possibly over 100. But from that 100 options, only six can be selected and added to the `<ul></ul>` . I need to count the .on-selected action and tally six max.

Comment: You can only select one option from a select menu. Are you sure you don't have the "multiple" attribute set so you can `cntrl` click on options and select more than one?

Comment: if you look at the code, once one option is selected, it gets appended to a `<li></li>` and then you can go to the search box again to select another option.  I cannot use "Multiple" because the options aren't accumulated in the search box, and I tried using this option but nothing happened for some odd reason.